# How to submit this form on this webpage with Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

In short, I'm interested in downloading search results from [this](http://www.oreillyauto.com/site/c/search/Brake+Pads+&+Shoes/C0068/C0009.oap?model=G6&vi=1432754&year=2006&make=Pontiac) website, but I'm running into a pop-up that asks for input. How do I submit that form using Python 3 (no Machanize) so that I can get to the search results?

This page: http://www.oreillyauto.com/site/c/search/Brake+Pads+&+Shoes/C0068/C0009.oap?model=G6&vi=1432754&year=2006&make=Pontiac

...has this form:

```
<div id="forcedVehicleQuestions" class="forcedUserInput" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 40px; z-index: 6000; margin-left: -199px; margin-top: 0px;">
        <div class="forcedContents clearfix">
            <a class="btn-remove" onclick="closeForced('Search','question');">
                <svg><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#shape-remove"></use></svg>
            </a>
            <form name="forcedQuestionsForm" id="forcedQuestionsForm">
                <h2 class="sans">
                    More Product Info Required
                </h2>
                <p id="questionText" class="questionText">
                    Brake Pads - Position
                </p>
                <div id="forceQuestionsRadio">

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label class="questionRadio checkbox-radio" id="questionRadio" for="Front">
                                <input type="radio" id="Front" name="answer" value="10219">
                                Front
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label class="questionRadio checkbox-radio" id="questionRadio" for="Rear">
                                <input type="radio" id="Rear" name="answer" value="10290">
                                Rear
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label class="questionRadio checkbox-radio" id="questionRadio" for="Show all">
                                <input type="radio" id="Show all" checked="" name="answer" value="-1">
                                Show all
                            </label>
                        </div>

                </div>

                <input id="questionSubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-green btn-shadow" value="Continue" onclick="setQuestionAnswer('Brake Pads - Position',document.forms['forcedQuestionsForm'].elements['answer'],'Show all');">

                <div id="forcedVehicleQuestionsLoading" class="loading load-sm">
                    <div class="spinner"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

...but there's no `method=` so POST and GET don't seem to work. I'm pretty sure I understand how to set the radio buttons, so all I'm really interested in is how to get the `onclick=` behavior to happen.

So far, this is what I'm using:

```
#import HTTP libraries
import requests
#import HTML parsing libraries
import bs4

url = 'http://www.oreillyauto.com/site/c/search/Brake+Pads+&+Shoes/C0068/C0009.oap?model=G6&vi=1432754&year=2006&make=Pontiac'
answerURL = 'http://www.oreillyauto.com/site/ConditionSelectServlet?answer=-1'

print("Making request")
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'referer': url})
r = session.get(answerURL)
print(r.status_code)

oreillyList = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

print("Writing response...")
logfile = 'C:/Users/mhurley/Portable_Python/notebooks/' + output + '.log' 
with open(logfile, 'w') as file:
    file.write(oreillyList.prettify())
print("...done writing "+logfile)
```

This code retrieves the HTML for the page, but without any search results.

Comment: It's js , i think you 'll have to use selenium.

Comment: It's likely that I don't understand it well enough, but shouldn't the JS be triggered by just submitting the HTML form? Or is the JS doing the submission?

Comment: Js is executed on the browser, `requests` just reads it as text. I recommended `selenium` because it runs js.

Comment: ah, that makes sense. Thanks!